# Improve on my way of selecting multiple XElements with unique values to build list

Tags: c#, foreach, hashset, xelement

Is there a way to improve upon this? I feel like I have way to many loops going on.

The code builds a string with domain names in it from an XML document. Depending on whether the domain name in the XML doc is in the hostSW (host Starts With), hostCN (host Contains) or hostEW (host EndsWith) element depends on whether I need to append a * to the end, beginning+end, or beginning of the value respectively.

I used a Hashset as a way of making sure that there is no duplication.

```
var startWith = xdoc.Root
    .Descendants("Test")
    .Elements("hostSW")
    .ToList();
var contains = xdoc.Root
    .Descendants("Test")
    .Elements("hostCN")
    .ToList();
var endsWith = xdoc.Root
    .Descendants("Test")
    .Elements("hostEW")
    .ToList();

HashSet<string> domains = new HashSet<string>(); //use hashset so we don't duplicate results

foreach (XElement test in startWith)
{
    domains.Add(test.Value.ToString() + "*");
}
foreach (XElement test in contains)
{
    domains.Add("*" + test.Value.ToString() + "*");
}
foreach (XElement test in endsWith)
{
    domains.Add("*" + test.Value.ToString());
}

string out = "BEGIN FILE ";
foreach (string domain in domains.ToArray())
{
    out += "BEGIN DOMAIN ";
    out += domain;
    out += " END DOMAIN";
}
out += " END FILE;

return out;
```

XML file

```
<Tests>
    <Test>
        <hostSW>startsWith1</hostSW>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostSW>startsWith2</hostSW>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostCN>contains1</hostCN>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostEW>endsWith1</hostEW>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

Comment: Is order of result output important? Should be same with original xml file or not?

Comment: How did you manage to write `string out = "BEGIN FILE ";`  when `out` is a keyword?  And `out += " END FILE;` with no close quote?

Comment: *improve* is such vague criteria.  Is reducing the number of the loops your only goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an XML structure like this

```
<Root>
    <Test>
        <hostSW>startsWith1</hostSW>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostCN>contains1</hostCN>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostCN>contains2</hostCN>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostEW>endsWith1</hostEW>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostEW>endsWith2</hostEW>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <hostEW>endsWith3</hostEW>
    </Test>
</Root>
```

I got all the domains correctly and only iterated 6 times with this code

```
// Loop each of the elements one time without filtering element name
foreach (var test in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Test").Elements())
{
    // Switch on the name of the element.
    switch (test.Name.LocalName)
    {
        case "hostSW": { domains.Add(test.Value + "*"); } break;
        case "hostCN": { domains.Add("*" + test.Value + "*"); } break;
        case "hostEW": { domains.Add("*" + test.Value); } break;
    }
    // For any other elements we iterate just do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Troy. My XML is slightly different. I have added the layout to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq to XML you can do:

```
var t = xml.Root.Descendants("Test")
    .Elements()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "hostSW" || x.Name == "hostCN" || x.Name == "hostEW")
    .Select(x => (x.Name == "hostSW") ? 
                       $"{x.Value}*" 
                       : 
                       (x.Name == "hostCN" ? 
                           $"*{x.Value}*" 
                           :
                           $"*{x.Value}"));
```

If your `<Test>` elements don't contain anything but `<hostSW>`, `<hostCN>` or `<hostEW>` then you can omit the `Where`.

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HM1yqy)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried working with [SelectSingleNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netframework-4.8) or the [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8) method with the [XmlNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode?view=netframework-4.8) class? I know you are trying to avoid loops, but for this scenario you should be receiving a time complexity of O(n), as long as we know the root(parent nodes) stay the same.

It looks like your XML file has nodes containing the inner text you need, so you could do something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes($"//Test/Test"))
{
    switch (node.Name)
    {
        case "hostSW":
            var newInnerText = node.InnerText + '*';
            //do something
            break;
        case "hostCN":
            var newInnerText = node.InnerText + '*';
            //do something
            break;
        case "hostEW":
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way.  This uses a LINQ `Select` instead of the loop, and uses a `Dictionary` instead of the `switch` / ternary tree.  It also leverages a substitution mechanism: in this case I used `string.Format` but many others including `string.Replace` would be similarly appropriate.  It all depends what you're going for.  I usually go for reasonable performance with economical syntax, which usually scores good points for ease of maintenance.

```
static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "hostSW", "{0}*" },
    { "hostCN", "*{0}*" },
    { "hostEW", "*{0}" },
};

static IEnumerable<string> WildcardStringsFromXML(XDocument xdoc)
{
    return xdoc.Root.Descendants("Test").Elements()
               .Select(item => string.Format(dict[item.Name.LocalName], item.Value));
}
```